# Using ROBOCOPY or Batch Script to Copy .doc File From Different Sub-Directories

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-prompt, robocopy

I currently have this folder structure:

```
C:\Quarter1\Folder100\Q1Review100.doc
C:\Quarter1\Folder101\Q1Review101.doc 
  ...
C:\Quarter1\Folder120\Q1Review120.doc
```

I also have another directory following the same structure except without the .doc files:

```
C:\Quarter2\Folder100\
C:\Quarter2\Folder101\
…
C:\Quarter2\Folder120\
```

My question is, how can I write a batch script or use ROBOCOPY so that I can copy all the .doc files from:

```
C:\Quarter1\Folder100\*.doc
C:\Quarter1\Folder101\*.doc
…
C:\Quarter1\Folder120\*.doc
```

to a directories:

```
C:\Quarter2\Folder100\
C:\Quarter2\Folder101\
…
C:\Quarter2\Folder120\
```

But instead of Q1Review100.doc as the name, I’d like to rename `Q1` to `Q2`, so the file should be copied and renamed to Q2Review100.doc.

Please let me know if I need to clarify this more.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue two commands:

1. copy all files:
   `robocopy C:\Quarter1 C:\Quarter2 /S`
2. Replace Q1 in all filenames to Q2:
   `for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in ('dir /b /s "c:\Quarter2\*.doc"') do Set LIST=%i& set LIST | ren "%~fi" "%LIST:Q1=Q2%"`

Note: if you write it in a batch file replace %i with %%i